# How to catch a JSONObject sent via POSTMAN in a Springboot application?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, postman

Following is my controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("identity/v1/")
public class InvestigateTargetController {
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "receive",
  produces = OneplatformMediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<InvestigateOutputResource>
     processRequest(@RequestBody JSONObject jsonObject) {

    System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);

  }
}
```

I am trying to send a json object to this controller via POSTMAN. But when I print  `jsonObject.toString()` the output is `{}` ( empty ). Following are snapshots of POSTMAN:

[image][image]

Where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Instead of `JSONObject` catch it in a string type.

Answer (score 1):

Create a java class having properties (with getters and setters) same as json object and put it as requestbody.